# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. on Android Studio

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Daniela Assunção\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Daniela Assunção\AndroidStudioProjects\teste1\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Daniela Assunção\AndroidStudioProjects\teste1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\Daniela AssunÃ§Ã£o\AndroidStudioProjects\teste1\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
>           at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Daniela AssunÃ§Ã£o\AndroidStudioProjects\teste1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-22.0.0-4fbb148ca6fa80976b43d144fa042cd2622996f3.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:214)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:144)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:158)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Daniela AssunÃ§Ã£o\AndroidStudioProjects\teste1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-22.0.0-ec2b9b9ca9b4235e047d77509ef5050f8f2c4141.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:214)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:144)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:158)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Daniela AssunÃ§Ã£o\AndroidStudioProjects\teste1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-6f40f2e7e7077677cc56a7f116bb7c6a2615c3b7.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:214)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:144)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:158)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Daniela AssunÃ§Ã£o\AndroidStudioProjects\teste1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-6f289279e5b24b3f989d62c45d58de54a83e9a1b.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:214)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:144)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:158)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       5 errors; aborting

Comment: When do you get this exception. Can you please explain your issue.